# Python subprocess.Popen memory error with readline

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am writing a python script which must launch a sub-process giving a heavy output (This output must not be written in my working environment). So I use `Subprocess.Popen` then `subprocess.stdout.readline()`.

Unfortunately, after several tests and research I cannot resolve my memory problem. After several iterations of process.stdout.readline() I get a list index out of range error, but since I can print the "problem" values ​​I think the problem is a memory problem.

I understand that `subprocess.Popen()` is starting a new subprocess independently from the main process, is there a way to give this sub process a certain amount of memory? / reduce the amount of memory used?

I tried running the sub process directly in the shell and it consumed 803MB in about 8 hours, if that helps.

Here is a part of my code and the error returned :

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["samtools mpileup -a -Q 0 -r " + REFERENCE + " -f " + REFERENCE + " " + BAM], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

mpileup_line = process.stdout.readline().strip("\n").split("\t")

while ((int(mpileup_line[3])<COVERAGE) and (int(mpileup_line[1]) != int(gff_line[3]))):
          if (i != int(gff_line[7])-1):
                    mpileup_line = process.stdout.readline().strip("\n").split("\t")
```

And here is the error :

```
[mpileup] 1 samples in 1 input files
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/work/cbirbes/axis1-assembly/errorCorrection_Pipeline/bin/Reductor.py", line 109, in <module>
      while ((int(mpileup_line[3])<COVERAGE) and (int(mpileup_line[1]) != int(gff_line[3]))):
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

And as i said, just before the error we can print both `int(mpileup_line[3]), COVERAGE, int(mpileup_line[1])` and `int(gff_line[3])`

Comment: Well, if you think it's a hardware memory issue, replace the memory or your whole PC. How can we help here? If you think it's a software issue (I think so), we need a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is that I can easily launch the job with a simple command in the terminal.
(My working environment is a SLURM cluster with plenty of memory)
I just don't know how i can give more memory to the subprocess (i tried to give like 200G to my main job, but still got the same error)

Comment: "List index out of range" has nothing to do with 200G of memory.